# How to find out the shipping cost of a product

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am building a sales channel, which users can install. Using Shopify REST API, I can get product details... but I am not sure how to get the shipping cost of a product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Shopify REST API you can try to access `/shipping_zones.json` endpoint and calculate the shipping cost based on cart items details and customer's address.

More details can be found here: [ShippingZone API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/store-properties/shippingzone).

There's no direct link to this resource on the [Shopify REST API reference](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference) docs (thanks [Hooman Bahreini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8211528/hooman-bahreini) for finding that), so it looks like Shopify wants you to use [GraphQL delivery profiles](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/manage-advanced-shipping-information-with-delivery-profiles) now.

Answer (score 3):

In recent shopify api version update you can get more control over shipping rules. You can create per product shipping rules with new Delivery Profiles API. Please go through [Delivery Api](https://shopify.dev/changelog/create-per-product-shipping-rules-with-our-new-delivery-profiles-api).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have checked [this](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/manage-advanced-shipping-information-with-delivery-profiles) document and it seems like the  Delivery API end points are *unstable*?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini yes it is unstable version for now you can test with new store developer preview